# Add Json inside array dynamically

Tags: json, spring, rest, controller

I have a problem with Json using spring tools suite.

> @RequestMapping(value = "/homes{fieldname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>       @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
>       public Set lists(@PathVariable("fieldname") String fieldname){
>           return pspnlRepository.findAllByFieldname(fieldname);
>       }

Here is my Controller to call my data from database through Repository.

And here is the Json what i got from this normal call :

```
 [
  {
    "fieldname": "field1",
    "inputtype": "text",
    "label": "Field 1",
    "labelgrid": 2,
    "inputgrid": 10,
    "inputlength": 15,
    "isrequired": "Y",
    "ishidden": "N",
    "isenabled": "Y",
    "issearchable": "Y",
    "content": "",
    "recordname": "psdbfield",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "field2",
    "inputtype": "email",
    "label": "Field 2",
    "labelgrid": 2,
    "inputgrid": 10,
    "inputlength": 15,
    "isrequired": "Y",
    "ishidden": "N",
    "isenabled": "N",
    "issearchable": "N",
    "content": "",
    "recordname": "psnlfield",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

And the problem is that i need Json like this one :

```
[ ---> how can i add this things here (0)
 [ -------> (1)
      {
        "fieldname": "field1",
        "inputtype": "text",
        "label": "Field 1",
        "labelgrid": 2,
        "inputgrid": 10,
        "inputlength": 15,
        "isrequired": "Y",
        "ishidden": "N",
        "isenabled": "Y",
        "issearchable": "Y",
        "content": "",
        "recordname": "psdbfield",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "fieldname": "field2",
        "inputtype": "email",
        "label": "Field 2",
        "labelgrid": 2,
        "inputgrid": 10,
        "inputlength": 15,
        "isrequired": "Y",
        "ishidden": "N",
        "isenabled": "N",
        "issearchable": "N",
        "content": "",
        "recordname": "psnlfield",
        "value": ""
      }
    ] ---- > (1)
] --- >> here (0)
```

And i need it to be a dynamic array, because the (1) is to define the front end level. so it depends on user (drag and drop) layout.